# Splitting field of $f=t^{4}+2\in \mathbb{Z}_{3}[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

In order to determine the splitting field of  $t^{4}+2\in \mathbb{Z}_{3}[t]$, I first "guessed" the roots $1$ and $2$ then, by polynomial division, obtained

$t^{4}+2=(t^{2}+1)(t+2)(t+1)$

Since for $t^{2}+1$ to be $0$ I'd need $\sqrt{2}$, I came to the conclusion that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\sqrt{2})$ is the spitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

Is my idea correct ?

Comment: I think you can use Hensel lemma

Comment: Can you simplify $\mathbb{F}_{3}(\sqrt{2})$? Hint: it is a finite field.

Comment: I just looked up the Hensel lemma and I think it's quite a bit too advanced for my current grasp of algebra

Comment: I know that all splitting fields of $f$ are isomorphic but just for now I don't see a quick way to simplify $\mathbb{F}_{3}(\sqrt{2})$

Comment: @ChristianSinger The splitting field of $t^{4} + 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ is equivalent to the splitting field $K$ of the irreducible polynomial $t^{2} + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$. It is clear that $K$ is a degree two extension of $\mathbb{F}_{3}$. The unique such extension is $\mathbb{F}_{3^{2}} = \mathbb{F}_{9}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but I don't think that the expression $\sqrt2$ is used in this context. I would say that the splitting field of $t^4+2$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3[t]/(t^2+1)$ or that it is$$\{a+bs\,|\,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3\},$$where $s^2=2.$

Comment: Yeah, I see your point.

Comment: I hope that it is clear that I am *not* criticizing your reasoning, but just the choice of notation.

Comment: Yeah sure! I appreciate your response :-)